# How to fix font size issues in management studio

Tags: windows-10, fonts, sql-management-studio

Under my Windows 10 Pro Version 1607 Build 14393.321 i recently ran in into font-size issues inside of management studio (see screenshots below).

I am not certain if the cause of the "font-size issues" appeared

- after i Installed redgate sql source control 5.3 on  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.2500.0
- or if an Win 10 update was responsible

### Font size in Management Studio while still loading plugins

It seems that at first the font-issue are not present until redgate loads

[image: Font size before redgate is loaded]

#### Font-Size after plugin was loaded

But as you can see after the plugin was loaded the fonts are squished.

[image: Font Size after plugin loads]

[image: Buggy option dialogues]

#### What have i tried

My `/settings/system/display/` for screen and text are set to 150% (for more info see [how to change icon and system text size](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/change-icon-and-system-text-size-on-windows-10/)).

The answer to [Windows 10 is squashing a few buttons, labels](https://superuser.com/questions/1123513/) was to go to `"Settings" > "System" > "Display"` and make sure the slider is set to 100%.

#### Question

But this is not an option for me because the fonts in every application are to small that way.

- What can i do get my old settings inside management studio back?
- What can i do to get rid of the tiny font-size and the huge icons in management studio?

Answer (score 0):

By chance i have run into [SSMS in High-DPI Displays: How to Stop the Madness](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/):

> The only complaint with it is windows and its (in)ability to scale
>   applications when running at High DPI.
>   I am running at maximum resolution (3200 x 1800) with 200% scale factor ....
>   [some] applications scale horribly. For instance, SSMS (SQL Server 
>   Management Studio) 2014 is a complete disaster

[Scott Hanselman posted Examples of Poor High-DPI behavior](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx) in early 2014.

Taken from comments from 2013 from [the Connect item that describes this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764009/ssms-does-not-display-properly-in-high-dpi):

> Walter A Jokiel, Program Manager, SQL Server: 
>   You can quickly implement that change yourself by following the
>   "[Disable display scaling on high DPI settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows)" instructions here
>   rather than waiting for a SQL release vehicle to universally implement
>   the change. Please let us know if this doesn't work for you.
>
> Adam Robinson: Hi, thanks for responding. While
>   I can understand this being a lower priority, could you at least
>   modify the application manifest so that Windows runs SSMS in
>   compatibility mode? This will render everything at the default DPI, so
>   things might be blurry, but at least the text in dialogs would be
>   readable.

With [SSMS 2016 this may be fixed](https://www.petri.com/sql-server-2016-subtle-changes-provide-big-wins) (not tested myself yet). Otherwise you can try to check the [trello board for SSMS 2016](https://trello.com/b/M9NmFPfv/sql-server-management-studio-2016-enhancements)

Comment: The "Disable..." link is broken. Too bad that I still need this information today. I replaced it with another one pointing to a similar resource.

Comment: Marcell since your edit did not go through i added your proposed link and found another that may be helpfull.  [SSMS 16.3 Releaase: Initial high resolution montior support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/ssms-highdpi-support) or [How to disable display scaling on high DPI setting for windows 10?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-disable-display-scaling-on-high-dpi-setting/c546cd4c-c4b9-4cb0-8e7b-52fb8906ef70)

Comment: The Link  "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"  in the post is still broken. The second in your comment helped me well though